Are there any examples of exponential algorithms that use a polynomial-time algorithm for a special case as a subroutine (exponentially many times)?
There are many examples of exponential algorithms that use polynomial algorithms for special cases as subroutines. Still, I was hoping to see one that uses a well-known polynomial algorithm for a special case exponentially many times as the primary method of solving the general problem.
This is not just for the verification of a subsolution but also for the construction of the solution.

Are there any examples of exponential algorithms that use a
polynomial-time algorithm for a special case as a subroutine
(exponentially many times)?


To compute $e^x$, you add 1 (polynomial) $e^x$ times?

A class of typical examples of this arises in branching algorithms, where one branches into several cases until some condition is met that allows for a polynomial-time algorithm.
A well-known example for this is the branching algorithm for the Vertex Cover problem, where the input is a graph $G$ and a number $k$ and the task is to find a vertex set of size at most $k$ whose deletion makes the graph edgeless.
The easiest branching algorithm for this has running time $O(2^k\cdot |G|)$: as long as the graph has at least one edge $uv$ and $k > 0$ branch into the two cases to delete either $u$ or $v$. The running time bound comes from the fact that in each case the deletion budget $k$ is decreased by one.
Now the interesting observation is that this can be improved by solving some special cases in polynomial time. The easiest such special case is to consider graphs with maximum degree 1. These consist of isolated edges and vertices and can be easily solved in polynomial time. Now with the polynomial-time algorithm for that case at hand, we can use the following branching:
While $G$ contains a vertex $u$ of degree at least 2 and $k> 0$, branch into the cases to delete $u$ or to delete all neighbors of $u$. If the condition is not met, then we can solve the instance in polynomial time (since either $G$ has maximum degree 1 or $k\le 0$).
Since in the second branch one always removes at least two vertices, the total size of the branching tree is $O(1.62^k)$ and thus much smaller than for the $2^k$-branching.
Many improved exact exponential-time algorithms and FPT-algorithms use this approach. The final instances that are solved in polynomial-time can become much more interesting / complicated than in the example above. The proof for such algorithms that an instance to which branching is no longer applied can be solved in polynomial time is sometimes called termination lemma.

The cutting plane method for integer programming is such an example - it works by repeatedly using some algorithm to solve linear programming (with real variables), which can be done in polynomial time, and whenever the obtained solution isn't integral it finds a linear inequality which all integer points satisfy but the current solution doesn't and adds it.

This is a good example but I was hoping for something more combinatorial in nature.

@GEP - Given the ubiquity of integer programming, there is almost surely an algorithm for some combinatorial problem that is actually the cutting plane method applied to the combinatorial problem written as an integer program.

@AlexanderWoo that is probably true but I wouldn't call such an algorithm combinatorial in nature.

@GEP - I wouldn't be so sure - for example the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm for min-cut/max-flow is actually the dual simplex method for a particular pivot rule.  The point is that, if you translate the cutting plane method back into the combinatorial formulation, you might get a very combinatorial looking algorithm.  For example, SAT solving methods that involve adding implied terms probably are cutting plane algorithms.

The usual algorithm for integer powering $a^b$ by repeated squaring is an exponential-time algorithm that works by iterating a polynomial-time algorithm just polynomially many times.

The real answer here is that every exponential-time algorithm computed by a Turing machine $M$ is an exponential iteration of the polynomial-time algorithm “simulate one step of $M$”. This can be seen as a “special case” of the original problem if you understand it as “simulate $M$ for a given number of steps”.

Linear programming. (actually not programming, but name predates computer programming.) This is a matrix operation.
The standard simplex method is very simple, but has exponential worst case complexity. The worst case is not that common.
There are proven to be polynomical worst case algorithms, but those are very complex, so they do not outperform the simplex in many common scenarios.

Dynamic programming. The Held–Karp algorithm is a classic example that finds the exact solution to the Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP), and to several related problems including Hamiltonian Cycle Problem, in exponential time.
TSP(graph, source, target) {
  if source == target {
    return 0;
  }

  min = infinity;
  for neighbor in neighbors(graph, source, target) {
    tour_length = TSP(remove(graph, source), neighbor, target)
                  + distance(graph, source, neighbor);
    if tour_length < min {
      min = tour_length;
    }
  }
  return min;
}

Note: (neighbors only returns target as a viable neighbor if no other choice is available)
This algorithm recursively finds the shortest tour starting from each neighbor and returns the minimum of those. The time complexity of this algorithm is as follows:
There are $n$ possible start vertices and $2^n$ possible subgraphs. So this function will be called on at most $n.2^n$ distinct arguments (the target never changes). Each call runs linearly in $O(n)$ (as there are at most $n$ neighbors). Hence the time complexity is: $n^2.2^n$.
